# How do using linq find the list where a particular string exist?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class which contains two lists

```
  public class SchemaView
  {
        public int Version { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<EntityView> Entities { get; set; } 
        public IEnumerable<RelationView> Relations { get; set; } 
  }
```

and when I have multiple versions I will have an IEnumerable
with an ascending version number.

I am looking for linq query which can find me the entity or relation which have a property
== "something"?

But how would I make a select, where for both?

currently I have something like this, which only look into one list.

```
            .Select(x => x.Entities  )
            .Where(x => x.InternalName == entityName)
            .SelectMany(x => x.Attributes)
            .Select(x => x.InternalName)
            .ToList();
```

somewhere possible to add an or condition?
so that it search for an internalname named something in relations aswell?

the above one fails in searching in the list of relations, but can this search not be wrapped in the same linq, or do i need to make a seperate linq for this,
Or maybe something conditional.

can it be done more efficient that this?

```
.Entities.Any(x => x.InternalName == entityName) ? .Entities                                                                                                         
.FirstOrDefault(x => x.InternalName == entityName).Attributes                                                                                                             .Select(x => x.InternalName) : .Relations.FirstOrDefault(x => x.InternalName == entityName).Attributes.Select(x => x.InternalName);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Which entity does `InternalName` belong to, for example. Please edit the question and provide a [repro].

Comment: So you have an _IEnumerable<SchemaView>_ and want to extract from this collection all the entries that have a _Entities.PropertyA == "something"_ OR _Relations.PropertyB == "something"_. Right?

Comment: @Steve yes steve

Comment: Voted to reopen. I am sorry but it is very important to try your best to explain your problem when you post initially the question. As you can see the closure comes very fast if someone doesn't understand what you ask. 11 minutes in your case and today is not a busy day on SO

Comment: Linq is not magic. Querying two times the same set brings in a penalty on performaces. Better use a normal loop and then check every SchemaView one time only

Comment: I don't see why this question was reopened. It's all very vague "somewhere possible to add an or condition?" "something in relations" "maybe something conditional". What are we supposed to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a sequence of `SchemaViews`, and every SchemaView has zero or more `Entities` and zero or more `Relations`.

You wrote:

> I am looking for linq query which can find me the entity or relation which have a property == "something"?

Is there only one entity / relation with property == something? or can your SchemaViews have several Entities and Relations that have this value for a property. And are you looking for any property in Entities and Relations, or for some specific property, for instance property `InternalName`? And does only Entity have this property, or does Relation also have an `InternalName`? Or do you want to use for Relations a different property?

And once you've found such an Entity or Relation, do you want the complete Entity / Relation, or do you want to select some properties of it?

So many questions in so little text. Consider to edit your question and write a non-ambiguous requirement.

I think you meant this:

**Requirement**

> Given a sequence of SchemaViews, where every SchemaView has zero or more Entities and zero or more Relations, and Every Entity has a property PropertyA of some type TKey, and every Relation has a property PropertyB of the same type TKey. Also given an object `value` of type TKey, give me the concatenation of all Entities and Relations of all SchemaViews that have a PropertyA or PropertyB that equals `value`.

The problem is of course that a Relation is not an Entity, so you can't put them in one sequence, or it would be a sequence of `objects`, which probably isn't what you want. Apparently you also need an `elementSelectorA` which selects the properties of Entities and an `elementSelectorB` which selects properties of Relations, and both selected elements should be the same type.

You could of course use `Concat`, to concatenate the Entities and Relations:

```
IEnumerable<SchemaView> schemaViews = ...
IEnumerable<TResult> selectedEntities = schemaViews.SelectMany(...).Where(...)
IEnumerable<TResult> selectedRelations = schemaView.SeelctMany(...).Where(...)

IEnumerable<TResult> result = selectedEntities.Concat(selectedRelations);
```

You are right, if you would use `SelectMany` to enumerate all Entities, and `SelectMany` to enumerate all Relations, you would have to enumerate `schemaViews` twice.

If you create your own extension method, you could make it that all sequences are enumerated exactly once. Using an extension method, makes that you can use it as if it was a standard existing LINQ method.

If you are not familiar with extension methods, see [extension methods demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

There are two possibilities:

- make an extension method specifically for this problem with SchemaViews,
- or make a generic method that you can use for every sequence with two subsequences, which makes it some kind of `SelectMany` for two subclasses.

If you think this is a very specific problem that you will only see for SchemaVies, choose the first solution. If you think you will have to solve this problem also for other classes, choose the second solution

### SchemaView Solution

The following solution will enumerate every SchemaView / Entity / Relation at utmost once:

```
public static IEnumerable<MyResultClass> SelectDoubleMany(
    this IEnumerable<SchemaView> schemaViews
    string internalName)
{
    foreach (var schemaView in schemaViews)
    {
        foreach (var entity in schemaView.Entities)
        {
            if (entity.PropertyA == internalName)
            {
                // create a MyResultClass, using properties from entity
                MyResultClass result = new MyResultClass
                {
                   Id = entity.Id,
                   Name = entity.Name,
                   ...
                };
                yield return result;
            }
        }

        foreach (var relation in schemaView.Relations)
        {
            if (relation.PropertyB == internalName)
            {
                // create a MyResultClass, using properties from relation
                MyResultClass result = new MyResultClass
                {
                   Id = relation.Id,
                   Name = relation.Name,
                   ...
                };
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Usage:

```
string internalName = ...
IEnumerable<SchemaView> schemaViews = ...

IEnumerable<MyResultClass> results = schemaViews.SelectDoubleMany(internalName);
```

You can even intertwine it between other LINQ statements:

```
var results = schemaVies.Where(schamaView => schemaView.Id == 42)
                        .SelectDoubleMany(internalName)
                        .GroupBy(myResult => myResult.Id)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
```

This will stop enumerating as soon as one Entity or Relation has been found

To make it simple, I didn't use any LINQ. I think this is the most efficient method (well, apart from low level GetEnumerator / MoveNext). Only the elements that you actually will use in your end result are enumerated.

### Generic Solution

If you want it as generic method, you will need a lot of paramaters

- Input `IEnumerable source.
- Every TSource has two properties of type: `IEnumerable<TSub1>` and `IEnumerable. You need two collectionSelectors, like in SelectMany
- Every TSub1 has a property of type `TKey`; every TSub2 has a property of the same type `TKey`, you need a keySelector for this like in `Join`
- You only want the items with a TKey value equal to some input value.
- You need a parameter to convert every remaining TSub1 to a TResult
- You need a parameter to convert every remaining TSub2 to a TResult
- and finally: for full generic: you need an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`

My, this is quite a long list of parameters. But then you can use it to SelectDoubleMany every collection with two subcollections.

The parameters are similar to a SelectMany combined with a Where, only everything is twofold. First the one without EqualityComparer, like a lot of LINQ methods, it will only call the other overload.

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectDoubleMany<TSource, Tsub1, Tsub2, TKey, TResult>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,

    // Two subcollection selectors, like in SelectMany:
    Func<TSource, TSub1> collectionSelector1,
    Func<STrouce, TSub2> CollectionSelector2,

    // the two KeySelectors, like in Join:
    Func<Tsub1, TKey> key1Selector,
    Func<Tsub2, TKey> key2Selector,

    // the "InternalName" that you want
    TKey value,

    // Two resultSelectors that convert Tsub1 and Tsub2 into TResult
    Func<Tsub1, TResult> resultSelector1,
    Func<Tsub1, TResult> resultSelector2)
{
    // call the overload with an equalitycomparer:
    return source.SelectDoubleMany(
        collectionSelector1,
        collectionSelector2,
        keySelector1,
        keySelector2,
        value,
        resultSelector1,
        resultSelector2,
        null);                // <== null equalityComparer
}
```

The overload that does the real stuff. If the equality comparer is null, use the default equality comparer

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectDoubleMany<TSource, Tsub1, Tsub2, TKey, TResult>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> source,

    // Two subcollection selectors, like in SelectMany:
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<Tsub1>> collectionSelector1,
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<Tsub2>> CollectionSelector2,

    // the two KeySelectors, like in Join:
    Func<Tsub1, TKey> key1Selector,
    Func<Tsub2, TKey> key2Selector,

    // the "InternalName" that you want
    TKey value,

    // Two resultSelectors that convert Tsub1 and Tsub2 into TResult
    Func<Tsub1, TResult> resultSelector1,
    Func<Tsub1, TResult> resultSelector2,

    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
{
    // If the equality comparer is null, use the default comparer:
    if (comparer == null)
    {
        comparer = EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    }

    // code is similar to the code above, only generic:
    foreach (TSource sourceElement in source)
    {
         IEnumerable<Tsub1> subCollection1 = collectionSelector1(sourceElement);
         foreach(Tsub1 subCollectionElement in subCollection1)
         {
             TKey key = keySelector1(subCollectionElement);
             if (comparer.Equals(key, value))
             {
                 TResult result = result1Selector(subCollectionElement);
                 yield return result;
             }
         }

         IEnumerable<Tsub2> subCollection2 = collectionSelector2(sourceElement);
         foreach(Tsub2 subCollectionElement in subCollection2)
         {
             TKey key = keySelector1(subCollectionElement);
             if (comparer.Equals(key, value))
             {
                 TResult result = result1Selector(subCollectionElement);
                 yield return result;
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Although this is very efficient: every element will be enumerated at utmost once, only the items that you need will be enumerated, I'm not sure that you will reuse such a generic method.